# Where are HTTP errors handled in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, http

In my webapp I have code in a factory to authorize a user that looks like this:

```
function signup (email, password, firstName, lastName) {
  return $http.post('/api/login/signup', {
    email: email,
    password: password,
    firstName: firstName,
  }).then(function success (response) {
    AuthTokenFactory.setToken(response.data.token);
    user.currentUser = response.data.user;
    user.currentUser.show = true;
  }, function (httpError) {
    throw httpError.status + " : " + httpError.data; // Here an error is thrown
    return;
  });
}
```

I have noticed that when there is an error in my browser console, it is logged twice: once from the code I commented, and once from some other place (line 9839 or thereabouts in the angular code).

I only want to throw the single error message I am specifying. Is there a way to block the other one from appearing?

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: It is a `401` denied error. I am sending it from my server, I see where it is coming from, I am just trying to figure out what else is handling it besides that promises I have set up.